# How to list all non-native js functions of a rendered page in a browser developer console?

Tags: javascript, console

In a browser's console, typing a letter auto-populates javascript functions like below:

[Browser Console auto-populating js functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Wty.png)

The auto-populated java script functions contains both native javascript functions and the non-native javascript functions of the rendered web page. Is there any means by which i can filter the auto-populate to just display the non-native
 javascript functions of the rendered web page?

Comment: Thank you for the reply ! So from my understanding, i will need to append a +' ' for every function to identify if its a native js function or a non-native function. Is there a better way that i can have the non-native js functions listed separately ?

Comment: ok, specifically looking for chrome

Comment: misread the question - sorry - no, there's nothing